# How to safely upgrade unlocked phone?

Tags: updates, sim-unlocking, samsung-galaxy-s-8

I have a Samsung Galaxy S8 from Virgin Mobile that was SIM unlocked and I'm now using Mint. I was prompted for an update by Samsung and it relocked my phone, I had to contact Virgin Mobile to unlock again, which took several days.

I'm now getting prompted for another update. How can I install without having my phone relocked? I also have this permanent Notification saying my phone can't connect to the Sprint OMADM network ("Configuration not completed"), any way to make that go away? Can I just install a new Android image?